# How data is persisted in web page using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i am planning to move towards asp.net mvc.in webform viewstate handle data persistent after postback but how this is handle in case of mvc? if anyone design a site with mvc and use heavily jquery then we do not have to think about data persistent because then everything will be done through partial postback....no full postback will be there but if anyone try to develop a site with complex UI with full postback instead of partial postback then how one can persist data in page after postback. so please discuss what kind of trick people use in mvc to persist data. is there any built-in mechanism available? if yes then discuss how that built-in mechanism works. thanks

Answer (score 1):

ViewBag, ViewData, TempData, Session state, Application state, Data store.